# Rails - Validation depending on which controller it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers using the one model. One of the controllers need to validate_presence_of :name but the other one does not. How do setup the validation so that it does not error out on the one controller that does not need validation?

Answer (score 4):

You can either create two models:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ModelB < ModelA
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Then reference the correct models in the controllers.

Or you can just check for the name in the controller on create or update.

```
class ModelController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_name, :only => [:create, :update]
  # ...
  private
    def check_name
      #Handle it how you want, here's an example
      raise Exception if params[:model][:name].nil? || params[:model][:name].blank?
    end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the first answer. Sounds like a job for a child model class.

Comment: MattC, I agree, two models is preferable over the controller method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use validating unless it **always** applies. You can just use something like `@model.name.present?` to check if the name is present in the controller where you need that.

Answer (score 1):

another (convoluted) option would be to use a conditionnal modifier when setting the validation :

```
validates_presence_of :name, :unless => :skip_name_validation?

def skip_name_validation?
  @skip_name_validation
end

def skip_name_validation!
  @skip_name_validation = true
end

def save_without_name_validation
  skip_name_validation!
  save
end
```

then in your controller :

```
@object.save_without_name_validation
```

I find this somewhat more explicit. Bonus methods :

```
def without_name_validation!
  tap {|record| record.skip_name_validation! }
end

# on a relation :
def self.without_name_validation!
  map( &:skip_name_validation! )
end

# in a controller
@object.without_name_validation!.save
@objects.without_name_validation!.each do # something
```

I do admit, though, that the other solution is more elegant.

Comment: This gem essentially does the same thing without needing to code it yourself:https://github.com/npearson72/validation_skipper